# Nginx 404 not found when trying to load files in the directory

Tags: nginx

So I have a website.

```
www.example.com directory pointed at /var/www/html/
```

I can load a webpage at

```
www.example.com/foo/
```

The file for that page is at

```
/var/www/html/foo/index.html
```

that index.html has a style sheet and object in the foo folder and tries to request it using

```
www.example.com/foo/bar.css
```

However, `bar.css` returns 404 not found even though it's at

```
/var/www/html/foo/bar.css
```

What gives? The files have 644 user rights. If index.html can be found shouldn't the other files be too?

Comment: Update your question with the nginx configuration file(s) and relevant entries from your nginx-access.log and nginx-error.log

Comment: logs are located at /var/log/<application name>/

Comment: Maybe the execute permission wasn't set on the parent directory(s). In order to view files inside a directory, you must be able to execute the directories.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Your folders must be set to file permission 755 using chmod. I successfully got it working after the following steps:**

After changing the owner of foo/

```
$ /var/www/html# chown root foo
```

and the subfiles to root, as well as changing the chmod of foo/ to 755

```
chmod 755 foo
```

to mimic /var/www/html/ 's permissions, my files became accessible.

Remember to use

```
ls -l
```

in your directory to check for the right file permissions. Also check your access and error logs at /var/log/nginx/
(this is accurate for debian at the very least, since this is what I am using)

If you can't find your log files, use

```
find / | grep error.log > results.txt
```

and open results.txt with your favourite text editor such as
vi results.txt
(Assuming you're on a server and it's easier to read text files than the terminal).

Thank you to Richard for telling me to check my logs.